# Solr query ExternalFileField

Tags: solr

I have added new field type:

```
<fieldType name="testScore" keyField="sth" defVal="0" stored="true" indexed="true" class="solr.ExternalFileField" valType="float"/>
```

and added a new field to my solr index:

```
<field name="test" type="testScore" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

This is content of my `external_test` file:

```
doc1=1.414
doc2=3.14159
```

I can sort on `test` field. But my question is:

How can I query on `test` field? I want to retrieve all document where `test > 2`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a range query, for example:
`test:[2 TO *]` which will return all documents where test is 2 or above. To return all values above 2 you'll need to specify something like:
`test:[2.00001 TO *]` depending on your data.